# Late Arrival: What to do with the other two cards? (Guillotine)

Tags: guillotine

The "Late Arrival" card tells to look at the top 3 cards, and add one of them to the end of the line. What should one do with the other two cards?

[image: Late Arrival card from the Guillotine]

Comment: Not backed by any rule, but we discard the cards afterwards since otherwise we would know them already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the card doesn't tell you to do anything special with the other 2 cards they should remain on top of the deck in their original order.

This is supported by an answer to a similar question [here](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/235968/callous-guards-and-other-question).